# Make groups of radiobuttons

Tags: python, radio-button, tkinter

Is it possible that I create two different roups of radiobuttons.
I now have 4 radiobutttons with only one option. I want to 2 groups with 2 options
so i can click two options.

the code now:

```
Radiobutton(root, text="Ja", variable=var, value=1,
                  command=setValueTrue).grid(row=0,column=8)

Radiobutton(root, text="Nee", variable=var, value=2,
                  command=setValueFalse).grid(row=1,column=8)

Radiobutton(root, text="Ja", variable=var, value=3,
                  command=setValueTrue1).grid(row=3,column=8)


Radiobutton(root, text="Nee", variable=var, value=4,
                  command=setValueFalse1).grid(row=4,column=8)
```

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to create a new variable to be used in the second group:

```
Radiobutton(root, text="Ja", variable=var, value=1, ...)
Radiobutton(root, text="Nee", variable=var, value=2, ...)
Radiobutton(root, text="Ja", variable=var2, value=3, ...)
Radiobutton(root, text="Nee", variable=var2, value=4, ...)
```

Comment: @Glenn You're welcome. Please consider accepting the answers of your questions that solved them to help other users know they were the correct answers.